# Excel VBA macro to give Write access to file when Read-only property attribute ticked

Tags: excel, attributes, read-write, vba

My Excel File has this attribute ticked, which I want.

[image: ***enter image description here***]

Therefore it opens read-only. This file occasionally needs editing and saving.

It would be nice to have a macro(1) that could be run (when the file is open as Read-only) which switched to Write Access, in situ.

I would then make the changes and run macro(2) which makes it Read-only again.

This way I don't have to uncheck the property attributes before going into edit because sometimes you don't even know if you're going to have to edit.

Comment: I'm not sure, but one can't do it with VBA only. You need to access *command line* with `Shell`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a routine like this:

```
Sub MakeReadOnly(sFile As String, Optional bReadOnly As Boolean = True)
    SetAttr sFile, IIf(bReadOnly, vbReadOnly, vbNormal)
End Sub
```

called like this to make it read only:

```
MakeReadOnly "C:\blah.xlsx"
```

and to clear the read-only:

```
MakeReadOnly "C:\blah.xlsx", False
```

Ideally, you'd swap the bits so you didn't affect other attributes but this should do here.

Comment: Thanks Rory. your code coupled with ActiveWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadWrite and ActiveWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadWrite I can achieve what I want.